# Why are typescript class fields all undefined and not having a certain types default value?

Tags: typescript

```
export class Customer {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
 }
```

let customer = new Customer();

**Output in console log:**

`customer.id` is *undefined*

`customer.firstName` is *undefined*

I expected the `id` to be *0* and `firstName` to be *null* as default values when not yet initialized.

Why is that not the case?

I use TS 2.3.6

Comment: in javascript, as well as in typescript, the default value when something is not initialized is always `undefined`.

Comment: ok then default values do not exist but they do e.g. in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a default value, you'll have to do so manually:

```
export class Customer {
    id: number = 0;
    firstName: string = null; // Warning, won't work if --strictNullChecks is enabled
 }
```

Typescript won't fill in default values for you since it's unclear just what default would be appropriate in any given situations. For example, in your snippet you say that `firstName` should have a default value of `null`, but in another use case it might make more sense for it to be empty string.

Moreover, it might be out of scope for typescript to set defaults since ideally typescript is only checking your types, but leaving the code identical to what was written as much as possible (ie, strip out the type annotations but leave the rest as is). Thus, it's on the developer to define a default value if one is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Except it's in scope of class, class property declaration is nothing different to plain variable declaration. Say you do declare any variable without class,

```
let id;
let firstName;
```

in javascript and check it's value - it is `undefined` by default. Typescript just follows behavior of javascript does.